# Simple Website that Shows Reactjs + Redux

Tags: html, reactjs, redux

I am trying to learn redux and react and I sort of getting how it all works but every example I see is so simple that when I started my own webpage I got stuck rightway.

All the examples are just one or 2 components on a blank page, they might be styled to look nice but there is nothing else, no headers, footers, no nav bars nothing.

So for me, I have a header, footer, main container and a side bar, that lists all the users items that are clickable.

I have no clue where to write the static html(are they dump components or just html?), I don't know how to render multiple smart components(side bar, main container what displays contents of what was clicked on in side bar).

Every tutorial I see gets everything written to the one div

```
<div id="root"></div>
```

Do I have many of these for each area and then have mutiple of these?

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: The standard way in reactjs is to have one html element, and your react code builds all the other components on your page and puts them together to display your webpage. This means that everything is built by JS "on the fly". It lets you have better control with different components talking to each other. Now if you wanted some static elements, you can put those in your HTML, and just load the react part into a div like you have in your post.

Comment: You could take a look at some more complex `redux` applications like [SoundRedux](https://github.com/andrewngu/sound-redux). It shows how to build a complex application with many components. You can easily clone, run it locally and inspect all the code.

Answer (score 1):

`<div id="root"></div>` in your `index.html` is the "target" for your React application and only appears once. 
Similarly, you only need to render App to the reactDOM once. Your App component can then render multiple components itself, for example

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Header from './components/header';
import Footer from './components/footer';
import MainContainer from './components/main_container';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <MainContainer />
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This assumes you have created Header, Footer and MainContainer components. Your `App` component can be thought of (very simplistically) as a larger component that contains multiple components. Therefore, if you render App to `ReactDOM` you are effectively rendering the other components contained within App.

Please note: this assumes the use of webpack, babel and es6.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has a great tutorial for building app in react-native, this section explains redux things:
http://makeitopen.com/tutorials/building-the-f8-app/data/
This section is basically how to architect in ReactJS + Redux, so don't be afraid the react-native things, this section is almost the same as in web apps.
[you can find code here](https://github.com/fbsamples/f8app)